# What are these special functions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions

I'm writing the documentation for my esoteric language [Whispers](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), which specialises in mathematical functions. I've come across the following function which I'm not sure exactly which special function it is, and I can't remember where I found the definition. The code is

```
def Lc(z):
    return z*ln(2*sin(z*π)) + S(τ*z, 2) / τ

def S(a, b):
    f = lambda k: math.sin(k * a) / k ** b
    return Σ(f, [1, math.inf])
```

which, in $\LaTeX$ is

$$\text{Lc}(z) = z\ln(2\sin(z\pi)) + \frac{S(\tau z, 2)}\tau \\
S(x, 2) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(kx)}{k^2}\\
\text{Lc}(z) = z\ln(2\sin(z\pi)) + \frac{1}\tau \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(\tau kz)}{k^2}$$

Looking through lists such as [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_functions) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series) haven't yielded anything.

$S$ appears to be a related function/extension of the $\text{sinc}$ function, but again, googling around hasn't found anything.

Does anyone recognise either $\text{Lc}(z)$ or $S(a, b)$?

<sub>I do also have the derivatives and anti-derivatives of both the functions, and the full source code of them can be found [here](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers/blob/master/whispers%20v3.py#L1154) ($\text{Lc}$) and [here](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers/blob/master/whispers%20v3.py#L1189) ($S$)</sub>

Comment: By $\tau$, do you mean $2\pi$?

Comment: @J.G. Yes, $\tau = 2\pi$

Answer (score 3):

For $S(z, 2)$ have a look at the dilogarithm. For other $S(z, b)$, the polylogarithm.

Comment: That's helped me find the definition for $S(x, 2)$: a generalised [Clausen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function#General_definition)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing: happy to hear that!

Answer (score 3):

$S(a,\,b)=\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{\sin(ka)}{k^b}$ is a [generalized Clausen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function#General_definition), typically denoted $S_b(a)$. In terms of *the* Clausen function $\operatorname{Cl}_2=S_2$, $\operatorname{Lc}(z)=\tfrac{1}{\tau}\operatorname{Cl}_2(z\tau)-z\operatorname{Cl}_2^\prime(z\tau)$.